# Do you need to add activity listener to SystemService only once in Android? or also on resume()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, activity-lifecycle, searchmanager

For example inside activity listening for closure of SearchDialog you register listener here in onCreate():

```
android.app.SearchManager searchManager =     (android.app.SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchManager != null)
    {
       searchManager.setOnDismissListener(this);
    }
```

My question is will this remain a listener or do I need to set it as listener again inside say resume()? or one registered always registered.  I am not keeping a local reference to SearchManager.

Also why we are at it, is there any reason to check if a manager is null like this or is it safe to assume you will never get a null manager back?

Comment: if you want a 'robust' app, don't assume what you can't control. Use the null check, but do something helpful if it IS actually null. But if you are very sloppy, you could say: "If `SearchManager` is `null`, the whole app doesn't work and therefore it doesn't matter if it crashes or gets closed a clean way"

Answer (score 0):

1. The listener will persist across the entire `Activity`'s lifecycle, so you should set the listener in `onCreate`. Setting the listener in `onResume` is redundant and unnecessary.
2. The Android documentation states that `getSystemService` will return `null` only if the service name (in this case `Context.SEARCH_SERVICE`) does not exist. So as long as you are positive it exists, it won't return `null`.